# Generate Unique ID (fingerprint) for PC .Net

Tags: .net, fingerprint

i'm having throuble while i have to generate unique ID for a PC with my WinForm Application C#

The most of problems come from Virtual Machine. I use this [code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28678/Generating-Unique-Key-Finger-Print-for-a-Computer).

Even if i comment CPUID code it changes every times that i restart the Virtual Machine (VirtualBox).

How could take a unique fingerprint , considering that i could use Virtual Machine too?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use the MAC address? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544018/get-mac-address-of-computer

Answer (score 0):

This solution has some potential caveats, but you could use either the MAC address or the serial number of the HDD, or both:

Here's the code to get the MAC address:

```
/// <summary>
/// returns the mac address of the first operation nic found.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private string GetMacAddress()
{
    string macAddresses = "";

    foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
    {
        if (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
        {
            macAddresses += nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
            break;
        }
    }
    return macAddresses;
}
```

Here's the code to get the serial number of the HDD:

```
using System.Management;

public string GetHDDSerial()
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia");    
    ManagementObjectCollection managementObjects = searcher.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject obj in managementObjects)
    {
        if (obj["SerialNumber"] != null)
            return obj["SerialNumber"].ToString();
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```